# How do I print inside the loss function during training in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a loss function in Keras (Tensorflow Backend) but I am a little stuck to check the inside of the custom loss function. In fact, the print appears on the console only when I compile the model, after that there is no print. (I am just testing very simple custom function, I will create the true function when I solved this problem). I train the model using the `train_on_batch` function. How can I solve this problem?

```
def loss_yolo(self, y_true, y_pred):  
    print('inside loss function')
    loss = K.mean(y_true - y_pred)
    return loss

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=loss_yolo)

print('train on batch')
print(model.train_on_batch(x, y))
```

And the output is

> inside loss function
>
> train on batch
>
> -0.481604

Comment: I tried with the function x = tf.Print( ...) and then print(x.eval()) but I have the same problem

Comment: This will not work. And there is not much you can do. These functions are used to create a "graph", and all calculations are made internally by or in the graph. Prints are not part of the graph.

Answer (score 10):

The only thing you can do is not use python's print function, but for example, tensorflow's [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) function that is part of the computational graph. The documentation says the operation does nothing but each time it is evaluated it prints a message that you can specify.

You just need to be careful to place it correctly in the graph, something like:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    d = y_true - y_pred
    d = tf.Print(d, [d], "Inside loss function")
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(d))
```

A better option to look inside what is going on internally is to use the [tensorflow debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger).

Comment: How to print full tensor? in my case it print just `[[1 1 1]...]`

Comment: @mrgloom It's saying `[1 1 1]` *is* the value of your tensor - are you expecting something else?

Comment: With default params it doesn't print all tensor values with `summarize=1000` it does.

Comment: This no longer works, even replacing `tf.Print` with `tf.print`. What's the new solution?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, right. With tensorflow 2.0, tf.print() seems to not print anything

Answer (score 5):

I added the **output_stream** argument and tried this code in TensorFlow v2.4.1. Worked fine:

```
def loss_custom(y_true, y_pred):
    d = y_true - y_pred
    tf.print("\n y_true:", type(y_true), output_stream=sys.stdout)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(d))
```

Output during training:

```
Epoch 1/10

 y_true: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
 1/72 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2328 - accuracy: 0.3319
 y_true: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
 2/72 [..............................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.2087 - accuracy: 0.5250
 y_true: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```