# unable to run print statements from loss function when calling model.fit in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have created a custom loss function called

`def customLoss(true, pred) 
//do_stuff 
//print(variables)
return loss`

Now I'm calling compile as `model.compile(optimizer='Adamax', loss = customLoss)`

EDIT: I tried tf.Print and this is my result.

```
    def customLoss(params):

        def lossFunc(true, pred):
            true = tf.Print(true, [true.shape],'loss-func') #obviously this won't work because the tensors aren't the same shape; however, this is what I want to do.
            #stuff
            return loss
        return lossFunc

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)
    parallel_model.compile(opimizer='Adam', loss = customLoss(params), metrics = [mean_iou)
    history = parallel_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.25, batch_size = 32, verbose=1)
```

and the output is

```
Epoch 1/10
1159/1159 [==============================] - 75s 65ms/step - loss: 0.1051 - mean_iou: 0.4942 - val_loss: 0.0924 - val_mean_iou: 0.6933
Epoch 2/10
1152/1159 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0408 - mean_iou: 0.7608
```

The print statements still aren't printing. Am I missing something - are my inputs into `tf.Print` not proper?

Comment: You need to call the print statement through Keras' framework. Keras uses TensorFlow for its backend so maybe try `tf.Print()` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819438/keras-print-inside-loss-function-does-not-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because Keras dumps buffers or does magic, it simply doesn't call them! The loss function is called once to construct the *computation graph* and then the symbolic tensor that represents the loss value is returned. Tensorflow uses that to compute the loss, gradients etc.

You might instead be interested [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) that is null operation with a side effect that prints the arguments passed. Since `tf.Print` is part of the computation graph it will be run when training as well. From the documentation:

> Prints a list of tensors.
>   This is an identity op (behaves like tf.identity) with the side effect of printing data when evaluating.

Comment: Because it is still not part of the computation graph, you need something like `ptensor = tf.Print(ptensor, [ptensor]...)` and chain ptensor further down the computation. The print acts like identity.

Comment: I've added an exact line of code to the loss function, but it still won't work.

Comment: You are passing `weightedLoss` instead of `customLoss`? Maybe that's problem, without the full code it would be difficult to debug.

Comment: oops, sorry about that. it's fixed. All I want to be able to do is print things like shape of the tensors in the loss function. But I don't know how I'd be able to splice the computation graph to also take in shape.

Comment: Oh, if the shape is determined at compile time you can just `print(tensor)` and it will show it's known shape at compile time. If any dimension is not known it will show `None`, ex. `(None, 64)` where the first dimension is batch size (not known at compile time) and 64 feature size.